# developing custom android plugins using Cordova 6 and greater in eclipse ide

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I'm making a native plugin for android in cordova using eclipse ide. I don't seem to be able to find the cordova jar. I don't really want to use android studio as i'm writing the app in angular 2 in eclipse and everything i need is there apart from the jar for cordova.

How can i get the cordova jar into the project to i can access the api while i'm writing my custom plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can link the source files from the cordova project itself:

> /cordova/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova